# Play framework: Server monitoring and performance admin page

Tags: java, scala, playframework, profiling, monitoring

I am using Play 2.2.x with Scala. I want an admin dashboard which shows CPU/Memory, list of recent HTTP requests, performance and load metrics, logs, server console etc in a nice HTML charts GUI page. Is there a Play plugin or a Java EE drop-in I can use? [Takipi](http://www.takipi.com/)/[NewRelic](http://blog.newrelic.com/2013/06/05/play-2/) looks good but it does not have a [nice HTTP log UI](http://javamelody.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javamelody-core/src/site/resources/screenshots/statistiques.png). [JavaMelody](https://code.google.com/p/javamelody/wiki/Screenshots) looks good too but it is geared for traditional Java EE apps rather than a Play2 Scala app.

Comment: Can you not use some server monitoring tools like Nagios,Zabbix or SeaLion? Check this answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1015768/monitoring-applications-uptime-log-files-etc) if it helps.

Answer (score 3):

For metrics related to HTTP requests/JVM Stats Twitter's Ostrich is awesome: https://github.com/twitter/ostrich.

For CPU/Memory you can execute Unix commands to obtain the metrics by importing scala.sys.process._ package.

Since you are using Play! you can have a separate routes: one for number of HTTP requests managed by Ostrich Stats collector, one for CPU/Memory, one for performance metrics (also managed by Ostrich) and so on..

Answer (score 3):

We love using's coda-hale's metrics library for metering application, jvm, http and logging metrics.
http://metrics.codahale.com/

The metrics library supports reporting to various monitoring systems, e.g. graphite, ganglia. (There's a www.hostedgraphite.com service if you wish not to install graphite locally)

There's a metrics plugin for play framework (disclaimer: I'm the plugin author) here
https://github.com/kenshoo/metrics-play

Answer (score 1):

To monitor your play! application, you can use the typesafe console : https://github.com/sbt/sbt-atmos

But there is no log UI ...

For logs, if you want to query them (with a good UI), you can take a look at kibana with logstash : http://www.elasticsearch.org/overview/kibana/

Comment: +1, Typesafe console is a part of [typesafe activator](https://typesafe.com/activator), it even can be started manually,  so if you do not have sbt in your project, you still can use it.